# Array length coming back as undefined when including key and value

Tags: jquery, arrays, is-empty

**JQUERY**

```
var a = {};
$('#individual_users_result').find("li").each(function() {
    var added_domains = $(this).attr('data-id');
    var added_domains_text = $(this).text().trim();
    a[added_domains] = added_domains_text;
})
```

I am creating an array where I am including the key and value. I am trying to determine if the array is empty or not. I have confirmed using `console.log(a)` the results and it is producing exactly what I need.

When I use this to find out if the array is not empty I get `undefined` on `a.length`

```
if (a.length !== 0) {
    alert(a.length)
}
```

If I change this

```
a[added_domains] = added_domains_text;
```

to this

```
a = added_domains_text;
```

Then I get a length of `39`

What is it about me adding the key value when producing the array causing my code to show the `length` as `undefined`?

Comment: `var a = {}` is not an array, it's an object in JS. what in php is known as an associative array, in case the reference helps. to get the length of an object use this: `Object.keys(a).length` instead. FYI only: `var a = []` *is* an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be: `var a = [];`for an empty array not `{}`

Example:

```
var a = [item1, item2, item3];
```

Comment: ugh sometimes I need to slap myself for missing the obvious. Thanks man

Answer (score 0):

By using

```
var a = {};
```

you are initializing an object; not an array.

For array, use

```
var a = [];
```